# Check for installed django apps using django tags

Tags: python, django, tags

I'm writing code for an app can be installed like a module on multiple django projects, each of which could each be configured differently. I'm looking for a way to conditionally load a package depending on how the project is configured.

If a specific package is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` file of the project, then load the package with `{% load my_package %}`.

I'm envisioning something like:

```
{% if package_is_installed %}
    {% load package %}
{% endif %}

<body>
{% if package_is_installed %}
    {% use part of the package %}
{% endif %}
</body>
```

Is this possible with tags or some other html or javascript implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off keeping logic outside of the template files & having different versions of the templates.

To do this in a template means writing some python for a filter or a template tag, so it's much better practice to keep the logic in the view that conditionally selects the template.

```
if 'myapp' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    temmplate_name = 'myapp.html'
else:
    template_name = 'base.html'
```

Comment: That's good advice, thanks. I opted for something like what you described.